# Flexbox responsive layout pure css carousel on bootstrap

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, responsive

I've tried in many ways before asking your help.
My problem is the following: when I try to split in two rows the left and the right sides of a flexbox content, the result is not acceptable for a responsive layout.

An example, similar to my code, is findable on this codepen project:
https://codepen.io/pascaloliv/pen/LVZaeE

```
#scene {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: left;

width: $scene-width;
height: $scene-height;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

[image: similar case]

What I wish to do is a different view for the mobile responsive version of the layout.

Could I ask you for your help? Thanks in advance

Comment: `position: absolute` removes the element from the document flow. This may or may not be a factor in the issue you're seeing. Can you post a [mre] of your issue?

Comment: `the result is not acceptable for a responsive layout.` What is the acceptable layout ?

Comment: For "acceptable" I mean a valid result.